# How access to apt from a filtered network?

Tags: apt, vpn, proxy

The filtering and spamming is so high in my country. I can not access apt commands.
How do I use a VPN or proxy or some other tool to access apt?

Comment: What does spamming have to do with it?

Comment: @David spamming is like the one who downvotes without reason because it's a question against the network filtering.

Answer (score -1):

It could be that your country practices censorship, but I doubt they filter APT or Linux repositories. I suggest checking your network connection first. Using a VPN may solve your problem, but be careful when choosing one. Alternatively, you could try using a proxy app like Portmaster. It's FOSS. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you can not connect to the main software sources. You can try other software sources to see if you have access.

Here is the instructions to change the Ubuntu's main software source

1. Open **Software and updates** from dash.
   [image]
2. At the first tab from the **Download from** select other.
3. At new window appearing click on **Select best server**.

   - You can also manually select other sources from the left pane.

[image]